# Git revert - git reset --hard origin/<branch>

Tags: git

I have accidentally typed `git reset --hard origin/<branch>` (to be precisely, I mixed up some of my aliases). The problem is I haven't pushed my commits and they are now lost. Can I get them somehow back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `git reflog`, then `checkout` or `reset` to the SHA1 before the erroneous `reset`. (Maybe fix your aliases first.)

Comment: Well after some commands and changes it did work eventually. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I see you've recovered from this, but, here's the way to think about it.  You must view your commits in terms of the "commit graph": a set of commits (which I'll label with single letters) where each commit points back to its parent commit(s).  A chain with one branch and merge in it looks like this:

```
         C <- D
       /        \
A <- B            G <- H <- I
       \        /
         E <- F
```

All the arrows point back (or for the angled ones, back-and-up/down, where I don't have arrows available so I just use `\` and `/`).

Branches, like `master` or `devel`, are simply labels with arrows pointing to one of the commits in the graph.  (The special label `HEAD` normally just contains the name of another label, like `master`, so I write it as `HEAD=master`.  That lets you know, if there are additional labels, which one is the "active" one.  If we had color we could make it a bright red or green or whatever, but with text, we settle for `HEAD=`.)  So with two branches, we might have this:

```
         C <- D
       /        \
A <- B            G <- H <- I   <-- HEAD=master
       \        /
         E <- F                 <-- feature
```

This tells us that we're on branch `master`, that branch `master` names the commit labeled `I` (really some big ugly SHA-1 like `d1574b8...`—that's why I use single letters to draw the graph!), and that branch `feature` names the commit labeled `F`.

What git reset does—well, it has several jobs, but what it does with the *labels*—is to change which commit the label points to.  Since you're on `master`, if you `git reset feature` (we'll ignore `--hard` for now), you're telling git: "Erase the label `master` from wherever it is now and make it point to the same commit as `feature`, i.e., commit `F`."  This does not change the commit graph itself, just moves the label:

```
         C <- D
       /        \
A <- B            G <- H <- I
       \        /
         E <- F                 <-- feature, HEAD=master
```

Commit `I` is still in there (is retained in the repository) for a while (30 to 90 days by default) via of the "reflog", so you can find the SHA-1 for commit `I` through the reflog, up until those reflog entries expire anyway, and make your label point back to it, using another `git reset`.<sup>1</sup>

(The "remote branch" label `origin/master` is just like your own, local, branch labels, with one big difference:<sup>2</sup> it updates when you use `git fetch` or `git pull` to get new stuff from `origin`, rather than when you do things locally.  So it lets you locate commits within the commit graph, just like your own branches.  That's why you can use those names with `git reset`: `reset` just needs to identify the commit to which you want your current branch label to point.)

---

The `reset` command also has a bunch of mode options: `--soft`, `--mixed`, `--hard`, and some more esoteric ones.  These affect its *other* job.  Besides moving a branch label from one commit to another, `git reset` can update your index, and can also update your work-tree.  The `--soft` argument tells it: "Don't update either one!  Leave both alone!"  In this case, the *only* thing `git reset` accomplishes is to move the label.<sup>3</sup>

The default, `--mixed`, tell it: "Update the index, but leave the work-tree alone."  In this case, `git reset` moves the label, *and* updates the index to match the commit you moved to.

With `--hard`, you tell it: "Update the index, and make the work-tree match."  In this case it can erase work in progress, since it makes the work-tree match the index which it makes match the target commit.

Note that if you say `git reset HEAD`—i.e., you tell `git reset` to move the current branch from wherever it is now, to wherever it is now—the *label change* is actually *no change at all*.  If you're on branch `master`, you tell git to erase the label `master` and then redraw it to wherever `master` pointed before it just erased it.  It winds up pointing exactly where it pointed before.  In this particular case, the only real effect is any index and/or work-tree changes you ask for.

You can limit the index and/or work-tree changes to specific files, as well.  In full generality, you do this with `git reset branch -- path`.<sup>4</sup>  That means: "move current branch to *`branch`*, and also do a `--mixed` reset on the given *`path`*."  If *`branch`* is `HEAD`, the branch doesn't move, but the index entry for *`path`* is made to match the current commit.  In other words, any new version you `git add`-ed is un-done.  Hence `git reset HEAD -- foo.txt` tells git: don't move anywhere, but restore `foo.txt` in the index to the current commit, un-staging `foo.txt`.

If you leave out the *`branch`* part, it defaults to `HEAD`, so that's why `git reset` is how you undo a `git-add`.  The work-tree version remains in place but the index entry has been re-set.  (More precisely, the index entries for the files you named, if you named any, or for all files.)

With `--hard`, it wipes out changes in files, by resetting index entries and making the work-tree match them.  And it still defaults to using `HEAD`, so that's why `git reset --hard` (with no additional arguments) gets rid of all uncommitted changes (and hence loses your work, so you really did mean to get rid of them, we hope...).

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, you can do it without using the raw SHA-1: `git reset HEAD@{1}`, for instance.  Reflog names work wherever commit-IDs are needed.

<sup>2</sup>And a bunch of smaller differences, e.g., you can't make `HEAD` name a "remote branch".  If you try you just get a "detached HEAD", which is essentially a local branch with no label.

<sup>3</sup>This is useful for doing "squash commits", but—since there's `git commit --amend`—not much else anymore.  In the past, you could use it to back up one commit and then make a replacement, but now you can do that more easily with `--amend`.

<sup>4</sup>Actually, where I have *`branch`*, you can use *any* reference that can be resolved to a commit-ID.  This is why the reflog-name in footnote 1 works, for that matter.